# I can't access neither TFS nor JIRA from home

Tags: tfs, jira

I'm working on some project and my team uses TFS, the URL starts with 'http://tfs01:8080/tfs/...', I can access it from my computer at work, but I can't do it from my computer at my home.

The same is true for JIRA and this is the URL: http://tfs01:8000/secure/Dashboard.jspa

I'm getting this message in Chrome:

```
This site can’t be reached

tfs01’s server DNS address could not be found.
```

So what is the problem? Both are cloud-based applications that should be accessible from anywhere, aren't they? How to access them from a computer that is not in my office at work? Why I am not asked for a username and password or something?

Comment: Probably because the host name `tfs01` doesn't resolve to anything unless you're on your work's network.

Answer (score 4):

TFS isn't cloud-based, it's an on-premise installation. There's VS Team Services, which **is** a cloud-based offering. VS Team Services URLs are all over HTTPS and the URL would look like this: `https://<some identifer>.visualstudio.com/`

Jira has a similar distinction, if I'm not mistaken.

It looks like your company is using on-premise versions, which make the answer to the question "Why can't I access these services?" simply "Because you're not on your corporate network or connected to your corporate VPN."